# WordPress: Can’t connect to the Akismet servers

Tags: plugins

I installed the plugin Akismet to filters out spam comments. However, it shows that:

> Your site can’t connect to the Akismet servers.
>
> Your firewall may be blocking Akismet from connecting to its API. Please contact your host and refer to [our guide](https://docs.akismet.com/general/connection-issues/) about firewalls.

The status of my firewall is as the followings:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

It still doesn't work even I disable my ufw.

How do I make it work?

Comment: "Please contact your host..." - are you sure which port Akismet is using?

Comment: @Steve, it is **80**, as mentioned in the [guide](https://docs.akismet.com/general/connection-issues/).

Comment: There is code in class.akismet.php which will [try and upgrade the connection to HTTPS](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/akismet/tags/4.1.6/class.akismet.php#L1177), so it would be worth opening 443 too. But it should fall back to HTTP if that didn't work. Seems silly to me that use plain HTTP at all though, and don't document that it can use HTTPS.

Comment: Do other outbound requests from WordPress work, e.g. core and plugin update checks? Could it be something else preventing the request e.g. SELinux or similar? Or can you curl the API from the machine's shell, i.e. could this be blocked by a firewall at the host outside the machine itself?

Comment: @Rup, I failed to upgrade WP. It warned me mine, 5.3.2,  is already the latest version of WordPress. Actually, the newest version is 5.5.1.

Comment: OK, so it's a more general problem than Akismet then. I would enable port 443 as well if you haven't already, since I'm fairly sure the update checks will be made over HTTPS. But I still think it's worth trying HTTP and HTTPS requests from the server, to the WordPress servers if possible, from the command line outside the web server process to work out if the block is specific to the web server process or not.